# change the uitabbar default color tint

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

i want to change the default gray tint on uitabbar when it is not selected. my problem is that i tried the following code but it only shows default gray color first time after that it changes to mu required white color tint which is actually my images color.

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:nil withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mylib"]];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:nil withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"explore"]];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setFinishedSelectedImage:nil withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio"]];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setFinishedSelectedImage:nil withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search"]];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setFinishedSelectedImage:nil withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"people"]];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:(191/255.0) green:(2/255.0) blue:(6/255.0) alpha:1] }forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(191/255.0) green:(2/255.0) blue:(6/255.0) alpha:1]];
```

[image]

please help i want to get rid of this default gray and want it white colored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass UITabBar and it's viewDidLoad method do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   //Do your logic here...
}
```

Comment: same issue even in viewdidload

Comment: Make sure that you have this new custom UITabBar class as the UITabBar class in the interfaceBuilder.